# Insert values from one table to another with null

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm trying to insert values from 2 tables into 1 tables. I only want the values where a date is null. The problem is that it returns 0 rows inserted.

```
 CREATE TABLE "CLASE"."DISCOS" 
   (    "COD_DISCO" NUMBER(4,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "NOMBRE_DISCO" VARCHAR2(40 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "FECHA_PUBLICACION" DATE NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "MILLONES_VENDIDOS" NUMBER(10,0), 
    "FORMATO_INICIAL" VARCHAR2(3 BYTE), 
    "GRUPO" NUMBER(4,0), 
    "DISCOGRAFICA" NUMBER(4,0), 
     CONSTRAINT "CK_FORMATO" CHECK (FORMATO_INICIAL IN ('CD', 'LP')) ENABLE, 
     CONSTRAINT "PK_DISCO" PRIMARY KEY ("COD_DISCO")

CREATE TABLE "CLASE"."GRUPOS" 
   (    "COD_GRUPO" NUMBER(4,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "NOMBRE_GRUPO" VARCHAR2(40 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "PAIS" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE), 
    "FECHA_FUNDACION" DATE NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "FECHA_DISOLUCION" DATE, 
    "ESTILO" VARCHAR2(40 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "DISCOGRAFICA" NUMBER(4,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
     CONSTRAINT "CK_ESTILO" CHECK (ESTILO IN ('ROCK', 'SINFONICO', 'PROGRESIVO')) ENABLE, 
     CONSTRAINT "PK_GRUPO" PRIMARY KEY ("COD_GRUPO")

CREATE TABLE GRUPOS_ACTIVOS (
CODIGO NUMBER(4,0),
NOMBRE VARCHAR2(40),
MILL_VENDIDOS NUMBER(10,0));

INSERT INTO GRUPOS_ACTIVOS SELECT grupos.cod_grupo, grupos.nombre_grupo, discos.millones_vendidos FROM grupos, discos WHERE grupos.fecha_disolucion = NULL;
```

Comment: You can't "equals null" you "IS NULL" e.g. `grupos.fecha_disolucion IS NULL`

Comment: And please only tag a **single** RDBMS - SQL Server is quite different to Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

Insert seems to be *wrong*; apart from what you already saw as a comment (`NULL` isn't equal to anything; use `IS NULL` (or `IS NOT NULL`)), you've created Cartesian join between those two tables because you didn't relate them.

`CREATE TABLE` statements don't reveal that information as there's no **foreign key** there.

```
INSERT INTO GRUPOS_ACTIVOS 
  SELECT grupos.cod_grupo, 
         grupos.nombre_grupo, 
         discos.millones_vendidos 
FROM grupos JOIN discos ON ...        --> ON what? Are there any common columns?
WHERE grupos.fecha_disolucion IS NULL;
```